# How to change iOS simulator language to swedish

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

I want to change my ios simulator language to swedish, but i can't find this in settings. What can i do now to get swedish language.

[image]

Comment: Note that "Svenska" is right there in the list. If you want to test in a foreign language, you should at least know the name of that language.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are trying to test an application's localisations then there are easier ways than by changing the language on the device.

You can run the apps with a flag to indicate the country:

i.e for Swedish you can use the flag `-AppleLanguages (sv)`

Of course, on the simulator or the device, you can't run an app with a flag normally, except for when you are building and running it through Xcode, where you can set the launch arguments for each scheme.

I wrote about this in greater detail, with screenshots, and an example project: https://abizern.org/2012/03/18/simple-localisation-testing.html

This works for the simulator and the device, and you don't have to change any of the device settings.

Comment: @FabrizioFarenga Thanks for telling me - I've corrected the link.

Answer (score 47):

It is also possible to set the language and the region via the scheme settings as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Comment: Note change Application Language and Application Region, 
Not Default Location. I made that mistake :P

Answer (score 8):

Choose `Svenska`.  You can select the language through the settings just like you would on a real device. Languages are displayed in the target language, not the current language, as displayed in your screenshot.

Tap the row you want, then tap done (click in the case of the simulator). On device, make sure you can navigate back.

Comment: @Shahrukh The target language is the one you want to select. `Svenska` = Swedish,  `Dansk` = Danish, `Suomi` = Finish, etc. Just tap the row you want, then tap done (or click in the case of the simulator). Just make sure you can navigate back (especially on a device).

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 12

To do this, tap on the **active scheme** (the name of your app at the left of the active simulator) and then:

- Edit Scheme
- Run
- Options
- App Language